# ForEach @ Generixs

Tags: c#, generics

I normally see the use of,foreach @ generics as

```
    List<int> lst = new List<int>();
    lst.Add(10);
    lst.Add(20);
    lst.Add(30);
    lst.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

How can i achieve something similar:

`lst.ForEach(x => x *x )` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst.Select(x => x * x ).ToList();
```

Hope that helps,

Dan

Comment: Just to add to this, Dan's code returns an IEnumerable rather than another List: if you specifically need another List, then check out List<T>.ConvertAll.  (Or call ToList() on Dan's expression of course.)